# How to get java.io.File.list() same order as in Windows Explorer

Tags: java, windows

How to get `java.io.File.list()` same order as in Windows Explorer?

In a program I am creating the `Temp` folders e.g. `Temp1`, `Temp2` and so on. But when I use `java.io.File.list()` to retrieve the folder list, it gives as `Temp1`, `Temp10` and so on.

Please tell how to get the same order list as showing in Windows Explorer?

Thanks

Comment: Create your own Comparator and sort list with `Collections.sort()`?

Comment: But which type of sorting is required to match the list as windows order?

Comment: @Kishore: The question is not clear at all. Windows can sort by name, size, type, date, ...

Comment: @jlordo, Its default windows order. i.e. Temp1, Temp2 and so on

Comment: That's right, jlordo and if I remember correctly, sorting by name will also end up in temp1, temp11, temp2, ... Whoops, no. I'm wrong. It's infact 1,2,11 in Windows 7 at least.

Answer (score 5):

Windows Explorer shows the files sorted by name by default. Looking at javadoc for `File.list()`,

> There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array will appear in any specific order; they are not, in particular, guaranteed to appear in alphabetical order.

So after getting the file list using `File.list()`, you need to sort this by file names `Arrays.sort(file.list())` to get the required order.

Comment: Its giving the same order as default order of java. Plz given valid answers only.

Comment: That is not correct. Windows explorer uses a sort called natural sort that takes number parts of names into account.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write your own Comparator.  The Comparator would need to split the file name strings, separating them into sequences of consecutive non-numeric characters and of numeric characters. Then sort the sequences, converting a sequence of numeric characters to an integer before comparing.  Also, if the integers are equal (due to leading zeroes), then order the longer numeric sequence before the shorter sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation of this specific windows sorting algorithm called natural sort.

[Java - Sort Strings like Windows Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205020/java-sort-strings-like-windows-explorer)

In short it splits the two Strings to compare in Letter - Digit Parts and compares this parts in a specific way to achieve this kind of sorting.